# shape of the digits of the numbering of the theorems

Tags: numbering, theorems, arabic, arabtex

I would like to use arabtex style of numbers in numbering of the theorems in arabi package.
In the following example the first numbering is done by the theorem environment. The second numbering is done manually. As you see the shape of numbers are different. I would like to use the second shape of the numbers provided by arabtex for the numbering of the theorems. Is it possible to do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm,arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,english,arabic]{babel}


\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exer}[thm]{}
\theoremstyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\setfarsi
\selectlanguage{farsi}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}


\begin{arabtext}
\noindent
1.\\
2.\\
3.\\
4.\\
\end{arabtext}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is `\textbf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm,arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,english,arabic]{babel}


\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exer}[thm]{}
\theoremstyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\setfarsi
\selectlanguage{farsi}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}


\begin{arabtext}
\noindent
\textbf{1.}\\
\textbf{2.}\\
3.\\
4.\\
\end{arabtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to get a non raised period is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is still unsolved. As you see the shape of the first series 1, 2, 3, 4 (bold or not) is different from the shape of the second series 1, 2, 3, 4 (bold or not). I would like that the environment `theorem` uses the second series for numbering.

Comment: If fact the second series is a particular font provided by arabtex package http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arabtex.

Comment: @Name This depends on the `arabtext` environment. If you remove it, the result is exactly the same as the first series.

Comment: Yes exactly, but my question is about using the **second series** (not the first series) for automatically numbering. If fact I like the shape of the second series, as they are more calligraphic, that is why I like to use them for automatically numbering.